# is __pycache__ using precompiled byte here

Tags: python-3.x

```
 myfunction ():
   
    tries to ping elasticsearch DB using .ping and 
    returns the object
```

```
   
other function():

 try:
   call to my_function()
   query elasticsearch DB
 except:
   sendmail_function()
```

but at times,both try and except block is executed,also i find **pycache** folder is created, when Elasticsearch DB is unable to ping except block is executed (which is expected)
but what happens is,query on elasticsearch is also executed using try block and sendmail also excecuted in except block.

is it due to pycache folder which is sending mail? please clarify